# What solar battery charger is compatible with the Canon LP-E6 Li-ion battery

Tags: canon, battery

I am looking at possibly buying a solar charger for my LP-E6 Li-ion batteries that I use with my Canon DSLRs.  I have never seen a solar recharger since there are no stores that sell them within a 5 hour drive of where I live.  Since I can not pick one up and look at it, I was wondering if anyone can recommend a specific charger that is compatible with the Canon batteries before I order one online?

Answer (score 1):

The reviews of the one LP-E6 solar charger that I could find online were poor. Perhaps a better approach would be either:

1. Bring extra batteries, [available for ~US$15](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lp-e6%20battery). Eight or ten LP-E6's would still weigh less than a solar charger. According to [DPReview](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canon-eos-6d/12) of a Canon EOS 6D, that should be good for ~8,000 - 10,000 photos (though I don't know how long a video). That would still be lighter than a solar charger, and, unused, Li-ion cells can hold most of their charge for a year or more.
2. If you must go solar, then create your own system such as this: [15 Watt solar panel](http://www.harborfreight.com/15-watt-12-volt-solar-panel-96418.html), [12-Volt regulator](http://www.harborfreight.com/7-amp-solar-charge-regulator-96728.html) and your choice of 12 volt battery. Just connect a car charger for the LP-E6 to the battery. The advantages of this setup:

   a. You can charge the LP-E6 from the battery any time, even at night.

   b. You're not restricted to one camera battery type; any battery with an car charger can be used.

Of course, the disadvantage is having to carry the additional 12-volt battery.